# Adobe AIR window on second display?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

I need to open some windows in my application on a second monitor.  Is there any solution for this in an Adobe Flex/AIR desktop application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is. It's not exactly a 'chose control', but more like an option to know what kind of displays you've got: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Screen.html#screens

This way you can get the second display and then move your window to it.